# taking parameter values from ihttp handler

Tags: c#, .net, servlet-filters

Let us consider a sample website application and running in local host.say for example **www.asdf.com** . when ever the user hitting the url in browser

1. Can it can be  captured by inheriting ihttp handler or ihttp module to our class
2. If the url has been hitted by changing **www.asdf.com?t=value** is it possible to take that value.

In java this concept is used as servelet filters . Is there any thing like that in dotnet

waiting for your responses

Answer (score 1):

Modules and Handlers do two different things.

1. Modules plug into the application and request lifecycles and respond to any number of events along the way to affect some bit of functionality to each request. Usually, it for stuff like security, logging, compression, etc. For example, `FormsAuthenticationModule` responds to the `AuthorizeRequest` (amongst others) event during each request, where it checks to see if there is an authentication ticket, validate it, and then indicate to the current context whether or not the user is authenticated (and who).
2. Handlers are designed to wait for a request to certain paths or extensions and do something useful. For example, requests to .ASPX files are handled by a `Page` handler, which parses and executes an ASPX and its associated codebehind (if there is one).

Both Modules and Handlers have access to the `HttpContext` object, which allows them to inspect and in many cases manipulate the current application, the current request and response, the user, etc. So yes, either can access the query string values provided during a request.

I believe modules are most analogous to a servlet filters.

This module looks for the `t` query string and echoes it at the beginning of every request.

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule {
    public String ModuleName { 
        get { return "MyModule"; } 
    }    

    public void Init(HttpApplication application) {
        application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        context.Response.Write(string.Format("The value of \"t\" is {0}", context.Request.QueryString["t"]);
    }        

    public void Dispose() 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any equivalent to java filter in dotnet

Comment: oops, i'm sorry. you did say servlet _filter_. In that case, servlet filters are most analogous to Modules.

Comment: is der any filters in dotnet ?

Comment: There are many built-in modules, many more you can add from third parties, and as you can see in my example, they are easy to create yourself. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: hmmm thanks for your help will try it now if any dough will keep in touch